# How to create dynamic/transparent proxy in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In C#, we can use DynamicObject class for dynamic method invocation for example used to JsonRPC or so. In Python, using **getattr** and **call** does the same task. In general I need an object with no real methods that can be used as like containing methods. The name of the method and the arguments gets into a function and does the task. Using IoC we can do it uing Interception, but I need to know if is there another way (like dynamic in C#) without using interface and IoC.

For example, Zabbix API has many JSON-RPC methods like host.create trigger.get ...
There is a Python wrapper that helps you call them so:

```
from zabbix_api import ZabbixAPI
zapi = ZabbixAPI(server="https://server/")
zapi.login("login", "password")
zapi.trigger.get({"expandExpression": "extend", "triggerids": range(0, 100)})
```

Actually there are no attributes like 'login' and 'trigger within ZabbixAPI class!

Comment: Not Kotlin specific, but here's the Java equivalent: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

Comment: @holi-java If you mean 'WHat is your problem?', the answer is Kotlin dynamic does does not support JVM target!

Comment: @GregKopff No it is not what I need! I can easily write the same code using IoC! I want not to define interfaces! That is what 'dynamic; means!

Comment: @Kamyar can you update the description (maybe pseudo code) about what you want.

Comment: As far as I understand the C# Dynamic object, the idea is to create objects which don't have a type, and whose members and methods can set/called in a complete dynamic way, as, for example, in JavaScript. That doesn't exist in Java or Kotlin, which are type-safe languages. You can't call a method or set a property on an object without having a type for this object defining the properties and methods available for that object. If that's what you're looking for on the JVM, look at languages like groovy.